# When i click the "AboSee" tab, it opens the tab, but does not show the tab bar

Tags: html, css, web, tabs, tabbar

When I click on the AboSee tab, it opens the tab, but then the tab bar does not show.
Here is the link to my website: https://abohisham-ghanoum.netlify.app

[This is how it looks like before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie0aU.png)

[And when i click, it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5mp9.png)

So i want the tab bar and tabs to show when i click the AboSee button

Answer (score 0):

you didn't make a div for AboSee.
make a particular div for AboSee that you make for others.

after that if your code throw error then ask again.

Comment: Thanks, but i am a beginner to this, so where should i put the div